# django custom user model user creation issue: permissions not working

Tags: python, django, model, permissions

I'm making a custom user model in django, but somehow any new users created through the creation form is missing their assigned permissions (is_active, is_staff, is_admin), preventing them from logging in at all.

Can anyone show me where did I go wrong? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Code snippets:

**models.py**

```py
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def create_user(self, ID, name, email, privilege, password=None):

        if not ID:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a ID number')

        user = self.model(
            ID=ID,
            name=name,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            privilege=privilege,
            )

        if self.privilege == 'Admin':
            self.is_superuser = True
        else:
            user.is_active = True
            user.is_staff = False
            user.is_admin = False

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, NIP, name, email, privilege, password):
        new_user = self.create_user(
            ID,
            name,
            email,
            privilege,
            password=password,
        )

        new_user.is_superuser = True
        new_user.save(using=self._db)
        return new_user

class employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ID = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="ID", unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=225, default='this@mail.com')
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEP_CHOICES, default='')
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='')
    privilege = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='User')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

**forms.py**

```py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    ID = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = employee
        fields = "__all__"

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    ID = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = employee
        fields = "__all__"
```

**admin.py**

```py
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    add_form = CustomUserChangeForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = employee

    list_display = ('ID', 'name', 'email', 'privilege')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('ID', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('name', 'email', 'privilege')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('ID', 'name', 'email')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering = ('ID',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

**views.py**

```py
def employee_list(request):
    data_list = Employee.objects.order_by('NIP')
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'add_user' in request.POST:
            user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST, prefix='add')

            if user_form.is_valid():
                new_user = user_form.save()
                new_user.set_password(user.password)
                new_user.save()
                registered = True

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employee'))

    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(prefix='add')

    return render(request, 'employee_list.html',
                            {'SignUpForm': user_form,
                            'registered': registered,
                            'Emp_list':data_list})
```

Comment: I’m not sure if it’d fix your issue but normally on a model you inherit the mixins first and then the classes, so your model should look like `class Employee(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'priviledge' as a character field in the **Employee** model, which is very prone to error in user input, use a choice field instead.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
use_in_migrations = True

def create_user(self, name, email, privilege='member', is_admin=False, is_staff=False, password=None):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        name=name,
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        privilege=privilege,
        )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_staff = is_staff
    user.is_admin = is_admin
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, name, email, password):
    new_user = self.create_user(
        name,
        email,
        privilege='admin',
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
    )
    return new_user


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    PRIVILEGE_LEVEL = (
        ('Administrator', 'admin'),
        ('Staff', 'staff'),
        ('Member', 'member'),
    )

    # ID = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="ID", unique=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=225, default='this@mail.com')
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEP_CHOICES, default='')
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='')
    # privilege = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='User')
    privilege = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PRIVILEGE_LEVEL, default='member')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Also, 'id' is auto generated by django as the primary key field, so it doesnt have to be in the frontend form.

> By default the django model form calls **MyUserManager.create_user**.
>   and based on the modifications i made above, it defaults to creating a user
>   without permissions. Unless ***is_admin*** and ***is_staff*** are implicitly set to **True**

To create a ***superuser*** from your current form, you can update **MyUserManager.create_user** like so,

```
def create_user(self, name, email, privilege='member', is_admin=False, is_staff=False, password=None):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        name=name,
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        privilege=privilege,
        )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_staff = is_staff
    user.is_admin = is_admin
    if privilege == 'admin':
        user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

But i would advise you update your **CustomUserCreationForm** instead as such,

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
# ID = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = Employee
    fields = "__all__"

# ADD THIS
def clean(self, value):
    print(self.data)
    print(self.errors)
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    print(cleaned_data)
    return cleaned_data
# ADD THIS

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    # email, password1 = v['email'], v['password1']
    employee = None
    if data['privilege'] == 'admin':
        employee = Employee.objects.create_superuser(
            name=data['name'],
            email=data['email'],
            password=data['password'],
        )
    else:
        employee = Employee.objects.create_user(
            name=data['name'],
            email=data['email'],
            password=data['password'],
        )
    # User is already saved after calling BaseUserManager function.
    return employee
```

> **MyUserManager.create_superuser** calls the **MyUserManager.create_user** and updates it based on parameter passed to it.

Let me know if you need further clarifications. Cheers.

Comment: I changed my code following yours, but now it returns the following error: "Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'zeroapp.Employee' ". Is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: sorry, please ignore my previous comment, I called the wrong form instead of the custom user creation. The problem now though, is that it doesn't save the user data to the database (no errors either). I've added the view function as well in my question, in case it's needed.

Comment: Sorry for late replies. Did you also update the BaseUserManager? or just the Custom form?

Comment: I updated both of them, the BaseUserManager and the Custom form. (Sorry for the way long overdue response)

Comment: Sorry you said no error. Confirm it actually calls the form. In your view, add a print(1) command after "if request.method == 'post' " and then print(2) after "if 'add_user' in request.POST".  Confirm if 2 gets printed in the shell.

Comment: It seems to be calling the form, but the form somehow got invalidated. I added another print(3) as well after the "if user_form.is_valid()", and it didn't print. ('1' & '2' got printed)

Comment: Hello, Just updated the Form with a clean method. Its should show you whats missing from the form.